# Divs within a container not appearing to be center on the page

Tags: html, css

I have 6 divs within a container div, they unfortunately are not appearing to be central on the page.

They sit equally apart from each other and mostly it looks fine but the whole thing just looks shifted across to the left. I tried using 'justify-content: center' but that isn't actually doing it in this instance for a reason I am unsure of?

I am also using 'float: left' on the entire section, so this may be a part of the problem?

Mostly it's inline css but there is also some css, sorry for the confusion of using the two.

here's an image to illustrate how it sits slightly to the left:

[image]

html:

```
    <div>
  <section style="float: left;" id="quality__info">
    <span style="font-size: 3rem; font-weight: 700;"> Clear and comfortable </span>
    <p style="font-size: 1.7rem; opacity: 1; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;"> We remove the need to empty leaked water or clean fogged up glass thanks to the full-face design. </p>
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-12 wow fadeInUp">
      <div style="display: flex; -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;" class=row>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'cameraBlue.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> CAMERA MOUNTING </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> All gopro's and similar mountable cameras are compatible with the mask and can be secured on safely with the tools provided. </p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'Anti-Fog.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> ANTI-FOG </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> All air is circulated around the masks outer layer and away from the visual screen.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'anotherGood.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> EASY BREATHING </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The seacaster X1 controls the airflow by circulating it around the masks outer tubes, with a separate intake valve for easier breathing.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'goodBlack.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> ANTI-LEAK </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The Seacaster X1 uses a double-rim to seal against incoming water, it also provides comfortability with material designed to not irritate.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'goodPink.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> DURABILITY </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The mask is designed to withstand the pressures of being in the sea and being dropped on rocks on the beach. </p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'Full_Vision.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> WIDE VISION </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The wide, flat visual screen with the separated, internal nostril creates a full 180 degree view. </p>
          </div>

          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </section>
</div>
```

css:

```
    #quality__info {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.quality__text {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .quality__item {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
}


@media (min-width: 992px) {
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}

.titleDescription {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;

}

.pDescription {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.descriptionImage {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.descriptionImageAndText {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Try taking the `.quality__item` css outside of the media query. Does this fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove col-lg-11 class:

```css
#quality__info {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.quality__text {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .quality__item {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
}


@media (min-width: 992px) {
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}

.titleDescription {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;

}

.pDescription {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.descriptionImage {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.descriptionImageAndText {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section style="float: left;" id="quality__info">
    <span style="font-size: 3rem; font-weight: 700;"> Clear and comfortable </span>
    <p style="font-size: 1.7rem; opacity: 1; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;"> We remove the need to empty leaked water or clean fogged up glass thanks to the full-face design. </p>
    <div class="col-12 wow fadeInUp">
      <div style="display: flex; -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;" class=row>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'cameraBlue.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> CAMERA MOUNTING </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> All gopro's and similar mountable cameras are compatible with the mask and can be secured on safely with the tools provided. </p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'Anti-Fog.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> ANTI-FOG </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> All air is circulated around the masks outer layer and away from the visual screen.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'anotherGood.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> EASY BREATHING </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The seacaster X1 controls the airflow by circulating it around the masks outer tubes, with a separate intake valve for easier breathing.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'goodBlack.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> ANTI-LEAK </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The Seacaster X1 uses a double-rim to seal against incoming water, it also provides comfortability with material designed to not irritate.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'goodPink.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> DURABILITY </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The mask is designed to withstand the pressures of being in the sea and being dropped on rocks on the beach. </p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 quality__item">
          <div class="descriptionImageAndText">
            <img class="descriptionImage" style="width: 300px;" src="{{ 'Full_Vision.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Quick Connection" width="100%">

            <span class="titleDescription"> WIDE VISION </span>
            <p class="pDescription"> The wide, flat visual screen with the separated, internal nostril creates a full 180 degree view. </p>
          </div>

          <hr class="hrMobile" size="3" style="margin-top: 5px;">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ahed, why was the col-lg-11 causing the problem?

Comment: In Bootstrap, you should use col-lg-12 class in order to get width 100%. read more about grid layout https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/